# Why does my Android emulator look wrong?

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Xamarin under Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, including the intel HAXM hardware acceleration, but I have a problem with the emulator:

- None of the default Xamarin avd's seem to have been installed
- When I create one myself and run it, it doesn't look right.

The attached image should make it clear.  As you can see the top bar takes up about 1/5th of the screen height, and the bottom bar about 1/4.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

I'm also confused by the buttons on the right hand side.  Are they supposed to be there?

[image: Android emulator problem]

Comment: Open the AVD Manager, Edit the AVD and clear the **Skin** selection....

Comment: @SushiHangover : That does seem to help with the size problem, when I set it to 'no-skin'.  However, I think it also turns off the hardware acceleration.  When I use the skin I see a message about HAXM during startup.  When I use 'no-skin' I don't see the message and it takes way longer.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: this happened to me when updating from VS 2019 to VS 2022, skin path was pointing to VS 2019 which did not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

VS can use AVDs but it's better to use emulators for Android for VS. It is using Hyper-V virtual PCs.You need to download and run Visual Studio Emulator for Android, then download VMs

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on windows 10 home, which does not allow use of hyper V.  So I would like to get the alternative option working, as recommended in the Xamarin documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

Because the screen display size is too small. You should use an `AVD Device Template` to get a normal size:

[image]

When you launch it, make sure that the display doesn't get scaled. You can scale this, but you might accidentally make it too small

[image]

The buttons on the right are due to the `Skin` you have selected.

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you potentially are using the old version of emulators. Make sure to update your `Android SDK` tools and then re-create an emulator to benefit from the 2.0 emulators:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#dependencies

Comment: I did select the two options you describe (Device and no scale).  My sdk is version 25.2.3, so that should be ok? I created the avd today so that also should be ok shouldn't it?  Possibly there is an installation issue though, so if you have any ideas?  How do I check the version of emulators being used?

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot things seem to be working which weren't before, so I guess something hadn't finished installing.  I still find that when I use a skin I don't see any message about hardware acceleration HAXM working, but I think it probably is. With regards to speed, it improved dramatically when I selected the option to 'Use host GPU'.

The HVGA skin still looks wrong, but I downloaded some ones for the Samsung Galaxy which work well.